# Selecting adjacent element in nested elements using BEM model

Tags: html, css, less, bem

I want to add margin top if `hl-mweb-text-banner__cta` and `hl-mweb-text-banner__cta` are adjacent. I have the below in less:

```
.hl-events-items {
  .hl-mweb-text-banner {
     &__cta + &__fineprint {
         margin-top: 5px;
     }
}
```

which is compiled to

```
.hl-events-items .hl-mweb-text-banner__cta + .hl-events-items .hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

In html, I have elements nested like this

```
<div class="hl-events-items">
   <div class="hl-mweb-text-banner" >
      <div class="hl-mweb-text-banner__cta">
         Shop Now 
      </div>
      <div class="hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint">
         No Min. Max $100 off. 1x use. Ends 3/24
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

But the CSS that works in this case is

```
.hl-events-items .hl-mweb-text-banner__cta + .hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

How do I achieve this in less. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: In LESS: `.hl-events-items .hl-mweb-text-banner__cta + .hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
}` All valid CSS is valid LESS. Don't get hung up on nesting things unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

There is no elegant way to do this, but if you really like rules imbrication, it's possible.

## Tips: you can define local sass variable

The following code

```css
/* BLOCK */
.hl-mweb-text-banner {
  $prefix: &;

  &__cta + #{$prefix}__fineprint {
    margin-top: 5px;
  }
}
```

will be transpiled to

```css
.hl-mweb-text-banner__cta + .hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

## Full usecase

```css
/* BLOCK */
.hl-mweb-text-banner {
  $prefix: &;

  /* ELEMENT */
  &__fineprint {

    /* VARIATION */
    .hl-events-items #{$prefix}__cta + & {
      margin-top: 5px;
    }
  }
}
```

will be transpiled to

```css
.hl-events-items .hl-mweb-text-banner__cta + .hl-mweb-text-banner__fineprint {
  margin-top: 5px;
}
```

I hope it helps! Cheers.